# mysql add foreign key error 1005 errno 150 on indexed column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So I am trying to add a foreign key constraint and getting error 1005 errno 150. What I don't understand is that I am trying to reference a primary key, so this columns should be indexed already, no?

I have a contents table and I have a categories table with a primary key id.

I am trying to run

```
alter table contents
add constraint fk_categories_id foreign key (category_id) references categories(id);
```

This is to show the categories table id column:

```
show columns from categories \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Field: id
  Type: int(10) unsigned
  Null: NO
  Key: PRI
  Default: NULL
  Extra: auto_increment
```

So my question is, why I am getting err 1005 errno 105 when I am trying to reference a primary key?

Comment: Probably different datatypes between FK and PK **`unsigned  int`** vs **`int`**

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the two columns were different data types.

**[Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):**

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. **The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same.** The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.